# How can i manipulate an object while inside of a loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So i m trying to manipulate the object while going through the loop.
Well, its not working.. How can i make it work so the const `patient` has the property `lastActivity` inside of the `this.model` array?

javascript:

```
for (const item of data) {
  const patient = this.model.find(
     x => x.linkedUserId === item.userId
  );
  if (patient) {
    patient.lastActivity = item.lastUploadDate;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Does *anything* happen? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: when i look at the this.model array, the patient object doesnt have the property lastActivity

Comment: Is the code you posted inside some sort of callback function?

Comment: Probably lastActivity property doesn't exist on your object. Try to use Object.assign instead

`patient = Object.assign(patient, { lastActivity: item.lastUploadData });`

Comment: From where your 'this.model' does? Could you please post some more code.

Comment: Edited answer :)

Comment: @PatrykPanek that would make no difference; the assignment as posted is fine

Comment: Afterthat i m just saving the this.modal array. the problem is patient has the properties, but inside of the array the patient doesnt have those values.. Do i need to replace it ?

Comment: debug the code you will know .....you might wanna break the loop once `patient` gets last activity.

Answer (score 0):

The `patient` in the array itself is not updated, to make sure you are not updating a separate `patient` you can use a `for-loop` so that you definitely update the `patient` in the array.

```
for (const item of data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.model.length; i++) {
        if (this.model[i].linkedUserId === item.userId) {
            this.model[i].lastActivity = item.lastUploadDate;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can store data in `this.model` as an object you can update it easily. Consider the following model data.

```
{ 
    "abcd": { linkedUserId: "abcd", name: "user1" },
    "efgh": { linkedUserId: "efgh", name: "user2" },
}
```

Now you can update the model by doing the following.

```
for (const item of data) {
    this.model[item.userId].lastActivity = item.lastUploadDate;
}
```

To get model in the form of an array you can do `const model = Object.values(this.model);`.